# not finding the name of and plugin

Tags: vimrc, macvim

I've installed "[awesome](https://github.com/amix/vimrc)" config for my vim;

It has a plugin that shows some stuff on the left bar.

I don't know its name,

what's its name?

and how can I disable it

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale), which stands for Asynchronous Linting Engine.

It checks your code in the background and marks lines where there are syntax errors or other warnings that you should address. It typically uses external tools to check your code, but it comes preset with a list of tools it knows about and it will look for them in your system and use them when it finds them.

The Vim feature it uses to display those `>>` markers is called [signs](https://vimhelp.org/sign.txt.html), there's a `:sign` command and a `'signcolumn'` option to control them (that ALE uses under the hood.)

You can disable ALE by setting this global variable during initialization:

```
let g:ale_enabled = 0
```

Since you're using the [alix/vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) configuration system, you should probably add that line to file `~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim`. See the ["How to include your own stuff?"](https://github.com/amix/vimrc#how-to-include-your-own-stuff) section.

You can also disable it after Vim is already up and running by using the `:ALEToggle` command.